# Need help turning a jQuery object back into a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

(i am new. please bear with me.) I have a jquery object that I need to convert back to html to use. What I am doing is using jQuery's get to get the HTML DOM of a local file. The data returned is then made into an object and I perform some tweaks on it (like changing hrefs etc.)

```
    $.get(imagePath + "bloghome.aspx", function (data) {
        var pageHtml = $(data);
        pageHtml.find('a').each(function () {
            var longHref = $(this).attr('href');
            var tmp = longHref.lastIndexOf('ID=');
            var id = longHref.substring(tmp + 3) + '.htm';
            var newHref = imagePath.concat(id);
            $(this).attr('href', newHref);
        });
    });
```

the object is created in the second line and then i change the hrefs. What I need now is to turn that object back into a string so that I can write it to a file.

I am using PhoneGap but any help would be appreciated as I am stumped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way using `pageHtml[0].outerHTML`:

```
 $.get(imagePath + "bloghome.aspx", function (data) {
        var pageHtml = $(data);
        pageHtml.find('a').each(function () {
            var longHref = $(this).attr('href');
            var tmp = longHref.lastIndexOf('ID=');
            var id = longHref.substring(tmp + 3) + '.htm';
            var newHref = imagePath.concat(id);
            $(this).attr('href', newHref);
            var htmlString = pageHtml[0].outerHTML; //<-- Here
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do

```
pageHtml.html();
```

?

EDIT:  Using this will only give you the contents inside the main wrapping element, if you want the entire thing, you can use:

```
pageHtml[0].outerHTML;
```

instead.

Comment: `.html()` doesn't include the toplevel element.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your answer.  There, I have +1 it

Answer (score 1):

from http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
console.log(pageHtml.html());
```

Comment: `.html()` is the innerHTML, it doesn't include the top-level element.